# How to constrain an element width to the background image width?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

App using NextJS and Tailwind CSS.

The background image size is; width=800px, height=691px

Problem:
I can't get the size of the  element to constrain to the width of the background size. Setting the "w=[800px]" does not have an effect. Also "flex-grow-0" does not help either.

See current result in attached image as well as code.

Most thankful for any advice!

Current [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvL14.png)

```
Code: 
export default function Example() {
    return (
      <div id="main" className="container mx-auto p-4 bg-sky-200">
        <div id="maincolumns" className="flex">
          <div id="playerlist" className="basis-1/3 bg-orange-300">
            List of players_
          </div>
          <div id="field" className="flex flex-grow-0 basis-2/3 bg-football-field bg-no-repeat bg-contain h-[691px] w=[800px] justify-center justify-items-center">
            <div id="positions" className="grid grid-rows-4 max-h-full">
              <div id="goalkeeper" className="flex bg-gray-100">GK</div>
               <div id="defenders" className="flex bg-orange-100">
                <div>DF</div>
                <div>DF</div>
                <div>DF</div>
                <div>DF</div>
              </div>
               <div id="midfielders" className="flex bg-red-300">
                <div>MF</div>
                <div>MF</div>
                <div>MF</div>
                <div>MF</div>
              </div>
               <div id="forwards" className="flex bg-green-100">
                <div>FW</div>
                <div>FW</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that you used arbitrary value `w=[800px]` instead try `w-[800px]`, Also check this section in the docs for more informations on [**Arbitrary values**](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values)!